# Apache2 with flutter web app in localhost

Tags: web-server, apache-httpd

I've got a Pi 4 with Raspbian 10 and apache2 2.4.38, with default option.
I can put a "hello world" index.html in `/var/www/html/` and access it in Chromium (http://localhost), or from another laptop in my home network (http://piIP).

I've made a Flutter web application with (in a laptop):

1. flutter create -t skeleton flutter_skeleton
2. cd flutter_skeleton
3. flutter build web
4. Copy the content of flutter_skeleton/build/web to the Pi /var/www/html folder
5. In the Pi, sudo service apache2 restart

I can see the flutter app from another machine in the same network (http://piIP). However, in the Pi itself, with Chromium (http://localhost) I can only see the favicon and the title, but the page is blank.

I have accessed the developer tools in Chromium (Ctrl+Shift+I) and the console shows:

```
Failed to load resource:
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

is this an apache2 configuration issue or an issue with Flutter? Any pointers to what may be causing this or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Default renderer for web app is CanvasKit. In
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78235# they explain that "We don't yet automatically bundle CanvasKit for offline development." there is a workaround but I tried using the html renderer and it worked.

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```